How to choose energy window in Wannier90
Hello I have following questions on Wannier90:
If I want to produce Wannier functions for the bands in the range E1 to E2 eV, how should I choose the inner and outer windows?
Thanks in advance 
Teja

I wrote an answer to a similar question about a year ago; perhaps it can help with this one too!
